# Java JADE - develop multiagent application sharing SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, agents-jade

Currently I am trying to develop JADE app that would have multiple agents, each of them connected to one common database. I know how to manage SQLite application and I don't have any problems with for example displaying table in one JADE agent.

The problem is:

I create 3 agents sharing the same SQLite database, let's call them A, B, C.
I run them at once from another agent Z - this agent is only used to start agents A, B and C.
Agents should end their work when selected or inserted data from database. Sometimes, for example, agent A did his work, B and C not. Another time agents A and C did their work and B not (it is like hang forever). I got different agents ended, but never all agents finished their work together.

The code is really simple and all agents are similar:

```
protected void setup() 
{
    Object args[] = getArguments();
    if (args.length > 0) {
        id = args[0].toString();
    }

    addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour(this) 
    {
        @Override
        public void action() 
        {
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {                       
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TblTemp;"; 
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.close();

                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                sql = "CREATE TABLE TblTemp" +
                             "(AdID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                             " CategoryID INT NOT NULL, " + 
                             " Title TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                             " IsContext INT);"; 
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.close();

                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                sql = "INSERT INTO TblTemp SELECT AdID, CategoryID, Title, IsContext FROM TblWHERE CategoryID="+id+";";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.close();

                doDelete();

            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                block();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Never any exception is given.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

delete this instruction:

```
doDelete();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; can you please elaborate a bit why this caused the problem?

Comment: 'cause it kills the agent and we have a Cyclic Behaviour , so we need the agent stay alive